# add other inputs to form on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add other inputs to a form whenever the user need them..
but I'm using a range slider (jQrangeslider) and I want to call it when other inputs are shown..

- I think calling jQrangeslider or not is not what makes the problem.. but I'll give the full code
  the HTML use is:

  Temps:


       Jour

  ```
      <input type="text" name="jour1" />
  </div>
  <div class="span3"> <span class="top">Matin</span>

      <div id="temp-g-1-"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="span3"> <span class="top">Soir</span>

      <div id="temp-d-1-"></div>
  </div>
  ```

and The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var jour = 1;
$('input[name^="jour"]').on("blur", function () {
    alert('called');
    jour = jour++;
    $(this).closest('div[id^="jour"]').after('<br><div class="span3"></div><div id="jour' + jour + '"><div class="span3"><span class="top">Jour</span><input type="text" name="jour' + jour + '"/></div><div class="span3"><span class="top">Matin</span><div id="temp-g-' + jour + '-"></div></div><div class="span3"><span class="top">Soir</span><div id="temp-d-' + ++jour + '-"></div></div>');
    $('div[id^="temp-g-"]').editRangeSlider({
        valueLabels: "change",
        durationIn: 1000,
        durationOut: 1000,
        type: "number",
        bounds: {
            min: 8,
            max: 12
        },
        defaultValues: {
            min: 8,
            max: 12
        }
    });
    $('div[id^="temp-d-"]').editRangeSlider({
        valueLabels: "change",
        durationIn: 1000,
        durationOut: 1000,
        type: "number",
        bounds: {
            min: 14,
            max: 18
        },
        defaultValues: {
            min: 14,
            max: 18
        }
    });
});
```

});

jsfiddle example (without jQrangeslider): http://jsfiddle.net/p4LWf/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your added elements are not bound to the click event because they are not present at the time of the bind. You should use `event delegation` instead:

```
$('.row-form').on("blur",'input[name^="jour"]', function () {
//code 
}
```

More about `on` and `event delegation` http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: It doesn't work if I put it without the $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: @IderAghbal Of course it won't :) the document won't be ready! Just replace `$('input[name^="jour"]').on("blur", function () {` with `$('.row-form').on("blur",'input[name^="jour"]', function () {`